# Safely change column data type in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

SQL Azure has a dependency of each table being required to have a clustered index. I have two tables that have a FK dependency on each other, with one of the tables using the.  That data type needs to be changed from a VARCHAR to an INT.  This requires that the index and FK relationship be dropped temporarily to fix any potentially dangerous data, and then to alter the column to be the same data type, then restore the FK and index.

How can this be done without throwing errors in SQL Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this on SQL *Azure* specifically, but I'd recommend placing all the metadata changes in a transaction, and also to be safe get an exclusive lock on both tables:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

  SELECT 1 FROM FirstTable WITH (TABLOCKX)
  SELECT 2 FROM SecondTable WITH (TABLOCKX)

  -- drop FKs, alter tables etc.


COMMIT TRANSACTION
```